# How to compare the two XML files having data and filter out based on common things in java?

Tags: java, xml

```
<safe>
 <risk>
<evidence>Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0;) OR 1=1 --</evidence>
</risk>
<risk>  
<evidence>Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0;) AND 1=1 --</evidence>
</risk>
</safe>
```

---

```
<safe>
<risk>  
<evidence>Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0;) AND 1=1 --</evidence>
</risk>
</safe>
```

Comment: Consider this first two set of data is in One XML file and other line in another XML... So I want compare this two file and print the uncommon things which is present in one file and not in other... I'm able to read the two file now I want to filter out? Using regular expression can I do??? HOw?? Coz Mozilla/4.0 ---- AND/OR are common things.. So I thought of using regular expression... So that I don't need to write all things in one of the XML... I'm thinking of useing like this... for EX: Mozilla/[0-9].0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0;) [A-Z] 1=1 --

Help me in solving this..

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/ It's a very good xml comparator fo shearching diffs. It Contains an xPath Engine witch you can collect data with it easly